# jquery code repetition should be pretty simple

Tags: jquery, function, load

I cant quite figure out how to convert this:

```
$(function() {
$(".cell_1 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #arkitek_reel');
    });
$(".cell_1 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_2 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ab_sciex');
    });
$(".cell_2 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_3 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #stratos_');
    });
$(".cell_3 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_4 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #riken_');
    });
$(".cell_4 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_5 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #scitable_');
    });
$(".cell_5 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_6 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ubc_asthma');
    });
$(".cell_6 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_7 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #xcelligence_');
    });
$(".cell_7 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_8 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #lbsc_geneware');
    });
$(".cell_8 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_9 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #nr_micro');
    });
$(".cell_9 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_10 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #genII_knee');
    });
$(".cell_10 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_11 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #exiqon_');
    });
$(".cell_11 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_12 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #hpi_');
    });
$(".cell_12 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_13 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #plexmark_');
    });
$(".cell_13 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_14 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #siscapa_');
    });
$(".cell_14 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_15 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #RNAi_');
    });
$(".cell_15 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_16 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #k2_');
    });
$(".cell_16 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_17 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #nucleonics_');
    });
$(".cell_17 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_18 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ca125_');
    });
$(".cell_18 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_19 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cci_nursing');
    });
$(".cell_19 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_20 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cadherins_');
    });
$(".cell_20 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_21 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ascent_');
    });
$(".cell_21 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

into this:

```
var urls = [
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cadherins_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ascent_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #stratos_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #riken_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #scitable_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ubc_asthma',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #xcelligence_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #lbsc_geneware',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #nr_micro',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #genII_knee',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #exiqon_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #hpi_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #plexmark_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #siscapa_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #RNAi_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #k2_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #nucleonics_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ca125_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cci_nursing',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cadherins_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ascent_',
 ];
 $(function() {
    for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
        var index = i+1;
        $(".cell_"+index+" a").live('mouseover', function(){
            $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load(urls[i]);
        });
        $(".cell_"+index+" a").live('mouseout', function(){
            $('#gridInfo').stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
        });
    }
});
```

Successfuly... can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure they are behaving different? what's the difference when you execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `i` inside the event handlers, but at the time the event happens the variable has been used to loop the array and has a value beyond the last item in the array.

You need a closure where you can declare a variable for each iteration that can hold a copy of the index, so that it's not changed by the next iteration. You can use an anonumous function inside your loop to create the closure, or you can use the `jQuery.each` method to loop the array which uses a callback function so that you get the closure in the bargain:

```
$(function() {
  $.each(urls, function(i, url) {
    var index = i+1;
    $(".cell_"+index+" a").live('mouseover', function(){
      $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load(url);
    }).live('mouseout', function(){
      $('#gridInfo').stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
    });
  });
});
```

Note: You should check if you can use `delegate` instead of `live` to reduce the scope of the event handling. The `live` method checks every event that happens in the document, while the `delegate` method can be appied to an element and would only check the events that happen to it's children.

Comment: thank you so much, oh man it seemed like I tried that already wow. THANK YOU